# clj-webdriver: why show me the login page even if I have already logined in and let the site remember me?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, clojure, webdriver

Since I already signed in manually, if I close the web, and reopen the web again manually, it doesn't let me login again. So I hope if I use clj-webdriver, it also doesn't need me login in again. But it actually ask me to sign in. I am using

```
(set-driver! {:browser :firefox} some_url_need_sign_in)
```

Is there any parameter to control whether to used the saved cookie?

Answer (score 0):

It has been over 1 year without working with it but as far as I recall you can manage cookies through the [IOptions protocol](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/blob/d5719d7925ea52b5b679c392ebd075b2289f4364/src/webdriver/core.clj#L82)

```lisp
(defprotocol IOptions
  "Options interface, including cookie and timeout handling"
  (add-cookie [driver cookie] "Add a new cookie to the browser session")
  (delete-cookie-named [driver cookie-name] "Delete a cookie given its name")
  (delete-cookie [driver cookie] "Delete a cookie given a cookie instance")
  (delete-all-cookies [driver] "Delete all cookies defined in the current session")
  (cookies [driver] "Retrieve a set of cookies defined in the current session")
  (cookie-named [driver cookie-name] "Retrieve a cookie object given its name"))
```